# Type aliases in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Many languages have type aliases, that is, a way to define a short name for a complex (maybe templated) type. For instance in C++ I have this:

```
using SymbolMap = std::map<SymbolKind, std::map<string, Context*>>;
```

Now in TypeScript I have fields with this type as well:

```
class SymbolTable {
    ...

    private _localSymbols: Map<SymbolKind, Map<string, Context>> = new Map<SymbolKind, Map<string, Context>>();
    static private _globalSymbols:  Map<SymbolKind, Map<string, Context>> = new Map<SymbolKind, Map<string, Context>>();
}
```

which is, mildly said, ugly. Is there a way to make this a bit more reader friendly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [type alias feature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-aliases) exist in typescript as well, and you can use it like so:

```
type MyMap = Map<SymbolKind, Map<string, Context>>;

class SymbolTable {
    private _localSymbols: MyMap = new Map();
    private static _globalSymbols: MyMap = new Map();
}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20SymbolKind%20%7B%20%7D%0Ainterface%20Context%20%7B%20%7D%0A%0Atype%20MyMap%20%3D%20Map%3CSymbolKind%2C%20Map%3Cstring%2C%20Context%3E%3E%3B%0A%0Aclass%20SymbolTable%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20private%20_localSymbols%3A%20MyMap%20%3D%20new%20Map()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20private%20static%20_globalSymbols%3A%20MyMap%20%3D%20new%20Map()%3B%0A%7D))